# JavaFX key interruptions?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to write a game in JavaFX but I'm having a slight issue with it and that's the key listeners getting interrupted by other key presses. I'm using `scene.setOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent)` and it works. When the player holds down a key they move continuously but if they hit another key it forgets about the first key even if they let go of the second key. I'm trying to figure out how to allow them to do one action and then when the key they were holding is released if they're still holding the other one go back to that.

Comment: See if the techniques in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331519/how-to-get-smooth-animation-with-keypress-event-in-javafx) help. If not, post some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: This may be a problem with [modifier keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key).

Comment: @James_D I'm going to try that and mess around with it but it looks like it could possibly be the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331519/how-to-get-smooth-animation-with-keypress-event-in-javafx), though the requirements look slightly different. Similar techniques work, but if you just want to respond to the most-recently-pressed key, you probably need some kind of stack.

This example allows you to move a rectangle around the screen, with the up, down, left, or right cursor keys; only the most recently pressed key that is still down is used.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class KeyStackExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.SALMON);

        Pane pane = new Pane(rect);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);

        final double rectangleHSpeed = 100 ; // pixels per second
        final double rectangleVSpeed = 100 ;
        final double minX = 0 ;
        final double maxX = 800 ; 
        final double minY = 0 ;
        final double maxY = 600 ;

        final LinkedList<KeyCode> keyStack = new LinkedList<>();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            KeyCode code = event.getCode();
            if (! keyStack.contains(code)) {
                keyStack.push(code); 
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> 
            keyStack.remove(event.getCode()));


        final LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
        final AnimationTimer rectangleAnimation = new AnimationTimer() {
          @Override
          public void handle(long timestamp) {
            if (! keyStack.isEmpty() && lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
              final double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime.get()) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
              double deltaX = 0 ;
              double deltaY = 0 ;
              switch(keyStack.peek()) {
              case UP:
                  deltaY = -rectangleVSpeed * elapsedSeconds;
                  break ;
              case DOWN: 
                  deltaY = rectangleVSpeed * elapsedSeconds ;
                  break ;
              case LEFT:
                  deltaX = -rectangleHSpeed * elapsedSeconds ;
                  break ;
              case RIGHT:
                  deltaX = rectangleHSpeed * elapsedSeconds ;
              default:
                  break ;
              }
              double oldX = rect.getTranslateX() ;
              double oldY = rect.getTranslateY() ;
              rect.setTranslateX(clamp(oldX + deltaX, minX, maxX));
              rect.setTranslateY(clamp(oldY + deltaY, minY, maxY));
            }
            lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
          }
        };
        rectangleAnimation.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {
        return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried such a solution once, but it was stuttering. So is yours. When you hold the key down, the movement isn't smooth. Do you know why that is? When I log your deltas, I get values at around 1.5 and when it stutters I get ~3.2.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0_25-b18.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it on 1.8.0_20, 1.8.0_25, 1.8.0_40, and 1.9.0 (the last two are early access releases). I couldn't reproduce the "stuttering". What you say about the deltas seems to indicate occasional frame dropouts (so there is a longer time gap between frames); not sure why that would be. Is it platform specific? I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: If there's just generally too much happening for the frame rate to keep up, Stephen van Impe's blog shows some techniques for keeping the animation fairly smooth (by using a maximum time step per frame). [Part 1](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) and [Part 2](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input and investigation. I'll check that out and post a new question in case I don't find a solution. fyi, this is what I get when putting a System.out.println( deltaX ); at the end of your "if" clause in the handle method: http://pastebin.com/w8wfkxYx ... ie the parts with the "3.#" are the stuttering parts. When I simply disable the setTranslate method while keeping eveything as it is, the deltaX are smooth. I use your code, so the problem isn't in too much happening. Btw, it's also "visually" smooth if I don't do the elapsedSeconds calculations. Running on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a set of all keys currently pressed and just check them in a timer.  It doesn't eat many cpu cycles on my old machine. In motion it's 5%, but 0% when no key is pressed.

For a possibly faster solution use an `ObservableSet` and start and stop actions when a key is added or removed.

package keytest;

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class KeyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableSet<KeyCode> downKeys = FXCollections.observableSet();

        Circle circle = new Circle(10);
        Pane root = new Pane(circle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(evt->{
            downKeys.add(evt.getCode());
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(evt->{
            downKeys.remove(evt.getCode());
        });


        Timeline timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            javafx.util.Duration.millis(16), ae -> {
                downKeys.stream().parallel().forEach(kc -> {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {//why?
                        switch(kc){
                            case UP: circle.setTranslateY(circle.getTranslateY()-2);
                                break;
                            case DOWN: circle.setTranslateY(circle.getTranslateY()+2);
                                break;
                            case LEFT: circle.setTranslateX(circle.getTranslateX()-2);
                                break;
                            case RIGHT: circle.setTranslateX(circle.getTranslateX()+2);
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }));
        timer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timer.play();

        //I think this might be faster
        downKeys.addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<? extends KeyCode> change) -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()){
                System.out.println("start action "+change.getElementAdded());
            }
            if (change.wasRemoved()){
                System.out.println("stop action "+change.getElementRemoved());
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I'm thinking the parallel is stupid and the `Platform.runLater` costs more than the threading of +2 or -2 .  But hey, java8 that's why

Comment: Yup, parallelizing the stream here is definitely going to be counter-productive, since you have to reschedule everything back on a single thread anyway. One thing to note by using a timeline is that you hard-code the "frame rate" for the motion. You have it at (approximately) the current target frame rate for JavaFX (60Hz), but if a future release were to increase that frame rate, your code wouldn't be able to take advantage of that enhancement. Using an `AnimationTimer` ensures an update on each frame, no matter the frame rate.

Comment: @James_D Good tip about the timer, I didn't know that.  The only reason I tried to use parallel is if there was a lot of calculations for the movement, like collision detection etc..   Notice in my example that multiple keys can be pressed at once, so you could be running, firing, jumping, or whatever all at the same time.